# Upgrade Meizu MX4 ubuntu edition to OTA-10 fails

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-touch, phone, meizu-mx4

Yesterday an upgrade to OTA-10 was available on my Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Edition. I downloaded the upgrade, and clicked the "install" button. Confirmed that the device was allowed to restart, and saw the device restart and an ubuntu logo came up. After about 30-50 seconds the Ubuntu logo was replaced by a picture of a small sign/icon of a computer-chip with a red cross behind it. Apparently something went wrong - but no form of error message was shown. The device was unresponsive - only thing to do was turn it off. When turned on again, it booted like normal - but the device is back to OTA-9.1. That is, I see a few subtle changes in graphics, and under phone information it clearly states OTA-9.1. What went wrong? What to do about it? How do I get it to fully upgrade to OTA-10?

PS: The update/upgrade to OTA-10 is still available, and I have tried to install it a couple of times - to no avail. Same thing happens again ...

PPS: I have nothing special installed or developermode or read/write turned on, or played with apt-get etc. Plain factory reset phone, that has been used as a normal smart-phone and nothing else for a couple of months.

Answer (score 0):

I have excatly the same problem as you. I have filled bug for this behavior here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1568889

Comment: I should add that I cannot recommend doing a factory reset. I thought perhaps it would help upgrade to OTA-10 - but that completely bricked my device. Meizu bootscreen loops when doing a normal boot. Recovery mode leads to an Ubuntu logo, but device is unresponsive. Fastboot mode is available, but trying to ubuntu-device-flash a new recovery image has had no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem on a Nexus 7.

I just tried again, this time using a writable image, and issued this via ADB:

```
ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu
```

It worked!

I'm not sure if the writable image has any effect. You might want to try this with your current image, after making sure you're using the appropriate channel for your device.